# identifying the network activity of a process - Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

Tags: macos, mac

Is there a way to identify the network activity for running processes ?  I'm seeing some unusual activity on my computer (late 2008 MacBook Pro )

Comment: How detailed do you want this? Simply what processes are talking out? Or down to exactly what packets are being sent where?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quite a few - ranging from the simple to the more complex. Depends on what you're after in terms of detail, but if you want a nice, easy GUI frontend (that ties up process names with activity) then you could use something like [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) or [Hands Off!](http://www.metakine.com/products/handsoff/). They are actually firewalls, which have their own network monitors. So if you find something you don't like, you can always block it.

[image]

I also use [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) or [iStat Pro](http://islayer.com/apps/istatpro/) (free) which can give you differing view of process and network activity (but not combined like Little Snitch can).

Or for something more detailed you could investigate the terminal `netstat` command.

Comment: Little Snitch looks like just the thing I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to mention iftop which can be installed through homebrew. It's a free option.